# Not getting response in lambda function using express-json-compress node module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Not getting response in lambda function using express-json-compress node module

im using serverless framework where i didnt got the reposnse from the api but when i use node server i get the compressed response

```
app.post("/api/getDocAppoints", async (req, res) => {
   const c = await client;
   const db = await c.db("vytalconnect");
   const collection = await db.collection('teamusers');
   const data = await collection.find({
      speciality: "Orthopedics"
   }).toArray()
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
   // send compressed json data with header
   res.compressJson(jsonString);

});
```

> using this coz of lambda 6 mb response limit... thank you

Comment: Could you paste any errors or a log from the response and also how you use the library (express-json-compress)?

Comment: No error , code ran perfectly but there is no response `GET http://localhost:8000/api
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Why GET it 's a POST right ?

Comment: I changed it after...dont worry its the same on both sides

Comment: Can you try with a mock example and see if it works like this ?
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);  mock this line and comment all the others